# How to add two positions together in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

So I am trying to find which publisher has sold most books to us i.e. how much the cost of stocks ans sold units are. I currently know the answers because i've done it in 2 steps.

The database is:

```
books((book_id), title, author_id, subject_id
publishers((publisher_id), name, address) 
authors((author_id), last_name, first_name) 
stock((isbn), cost, retail_price, stock) 
shipments((shipment_id), customer_id, isbn, ship_date)
customers((customer_id), last_name, first_name) 
editions((isbn), book_id, edition, publisher_id, publication_date) 
subjects((subject_id), subject, location)
```

And I've used

```
SELECT name, cost 
FROM shipments, books, editions, publishers, stock
WHERE shipments.isbn = editions.isbn 
AND editions.book_id = books.book_id 
AND publishers.publisher_id = editions.publisher_id 
AND stock.isbn = shipments.isbn 
GROUP BY name, cost;
```

To find the cost of the shipped books and

```
SELECT name, cost, stock, cost*stock 
FROM stock, publishers, editions 
WHERE stock.isbn = editions.isbn 
AND editions.publisher_id = publishers.publisher_id;
```

To find the cost of the current stock.

However the only reason i know the answer is because i manually added them. Is there a way to sum the position in SQL with only one query? Note also that the publishers have different cost for different units from the publishers. I suspect it has something to do with the "join" and "sum" but I can't get it always bugs when I try to use them. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT:

To clarify

My current results are:

```
booktown=> SELECT name, cost, count(title), count(title)*cost FROM shipments, books, editions, publishers, stock WHERE shipments.isbn = editions.isbn AND editions.book_id = books.book_id AND publishers.publisher_id = editions.publisher_id AND stock.isbn = shipments.isbn GROUP BY name, cost;
            name             | cost  | count | ?column?
-----------------------------+-------+-------+----------
 Ace Books                   | 17.00 |     1 |    17.00
 Ace Books                   | 36.00 |     1 |    36.00
 Kids Can Press              | 23.00 |     3 |    69.00
 Doubleday                   | 24.00 |     4 |    96.00
 Books of Wonder             | 19.00 |     1 |    19.00
 Doubleday                   | 29.00 |     2 |    58.00
 Random House                | 23.00 |     2 |    46.00
 Henry Holt & Company, Inc.  | 18.00 |     2 |    36.00
 Roc                         | 17.00 |     1 |    17.00
 Mojo Press                  | 23.00 |     2 |    46.00
 Watson-Guptill Publications | 26.00 |     1 |    26.00
 Roc                         | 36.00 |     1 |    36.00
 Penguin                     | 20.00 |     2 |    40.00
 Random House                | 30.00 |     5 |   150.00
 HarperCollins               | 25.00 |     3 |    75.00
 Random House                | 16.00 |     6 |    96.00
(16 rows)

booktown=> SELECT name, cost, stock, cost*stock FROM stock, publishers, editions WHERE stock.isbn = editions.isbn AND editions.publisher_id = publishers.publisher_id;                                                                                   name             | cost  | stock | ?column?
-----------------------------+-------+-------+----------
 Random House                | 30.00 |    31 |   930.00
 Doubleday                   | 24.00 |    22 |   528.00
 Random House                | 16.00 |     4 |    64.00
 Kids Can Press              | 23.00 |    10 |   230.00
 HarperCollins               | 25.00 |    50 |  1250.00
 Penguin                     | 20.00 |    18 |   360.00
 Henry Holt & Company, Inc.  | 18.00 |    28 |   504.00
 Random House                | 23.00 |     0 |     0.00
 Doubleday                   | 29.00 |    65 |  1885.00
 Mojo Press                  | 23.00 |    77 |  1771.00
 Books of Wonder             | 19.00 |    25 |   475.00
 Ace Books                   | 17.00 |    77 |  1309.00
 Ace Books                   | 36.00 |    89 |  3204.00
 Roc                         | 17.00 |     0 |     0.00
 Roc                         | 36.00 |     0 |     0.00
 Watson-Guptill Publications | 26.00 |    16 |   416.00
(16 rows)
```

I want to add all the positions from "Ace Books". Manually adding the total together will give the answer that "Ace books" has sold the most books with the value 4566.

Well I'm now at correct answer but i suspect my method is incorrect and that the answer is only correct due to the specific circumstances in my case. Which is that Ace Books only ships 1 of each unit. Anyone verify if that is the case or if my answer is valid?

The Code i use is:

```
SELECT name, sum(stock*cost)+sum(cost) as total  
FROM stock s JOIN editions e ON s.isbn=e.isbn 
JOIN publishers p ON e.publisher_id = p.publisher_id GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY total;
```

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: its hard to understand what exactly you want.. if you can show us an example for the tables and the wanted result it will be great

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to `group by` each name. As Gordon mentioned in the comments, you should use `ansi-sql` `join` syntax.

```
SELECT name, sum(cost)* (sum(stock) - count(sh.isbn)) as total 
FROM stock s 
join editions e on s.isbn = e.isbn 
join publishers p on e.publisher_id = p.publisher_id
join shipments sh on sh.isbn = e.isbn 
group by name
```

Comment: I tried this and is does not account for the shipped units, so the total is 4513 which is all the units in the stock. Thanks though! I'll keep trying!

Comment: SELECT name, sum(cost) FROM shipments, books, editions, publishers, stock WHERE shipments.isbn = editions.isbn AND editions.book_id = books.book_id AND publishers.publisher_id = editions.publisher_id AND stock.isbn = shipments.isbn GROUP BY name;

Comment: this is incorrect as the query doesn't include any columns from `shipments` table

Comment: I changed it to sum(cost) from the first codeline i had and tried to do the same thing as you did showed me with stock cost and it summed up to the rest. Which is 53. Now i only need to add these 53 to the previous 4513 that your code gave me. I think the WHERE-statements made it fit together

Comment: see if the modified version is what you need

Comment: I've been trying this for a while now. The didn't work. And i tried using sum(cost*stock) on it also. It seems to account for some publishers multiple times i.e. the sum(cost*stock) for "Double Day" is almost dubble against if we do not use shipments.

Answer (score 0):

To get the calculations right, you first need to identify how many copies of each book you sold; that is the sub-query in the below answer. Otherwise it is rather straightforward:

```
SELECT p.name, sum(st.cost * (st.stock + s.books_sold)) AS total_sold
FROM stock st
JOIN (
  SELECT isbn, count(isbn) AS books_sold FROM shipments GROUP BY isbn
) AS s ON s.isbn = st.isbn
JOIN editions ed ON ed.isbn = st.isbn
JOIN publishers p USING (publisher_id)
GROUP BY p.name;
```